# Use HP LaserJet 4M with 18.04.2

Tags: laserjet

Wanting to use an HP LaserJet 4m with JetDirect card with my Ubuntu 18.04.2 laptop.

Settings -> Devices -> Printers lets me add it as a printer. A test print works, but when I try to print to it from LibreOffice nothing prints. The data light on the printer flashes indicating that it is receiving data then it just goes back to 'ready'.

David.

Comment: Try hplip -> http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/04/hplip-3-18-4-released-ubuntu-18-04-support/  - **look for the latest version and change accordingly in the instructions.**

Comment: Thanks. I'll get back to this when I've solved a more pressing problem - login failure.

Answer (score 0):

Turn ON the printer and connect to the HP printers server:

```
hp-doctor
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem some time ago. The problem was that while adding new printer I selected "wrong" driver but theoretically for my printer. To solve my problem I've downloaded this driver https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/gethplip and installed it on Ubuntu, then everything started to work.

Comment: Thanks. I'll get back to this when I've solved a more pressing problem - login failure